# onClick event isn't working in SVG Tic Tac Toe

Tags: javascript, html, svg, onclick, tic-tac-toe

I am currently working on creating a Tic Tac Toe game and have the code to make the x and o's appear. However, the onclick event isn't always being called when the squares are clicked, and randomly decide to work after many clicks. What am I doing wrong?
The javascript is at the top and the SVG elements are at the bottom

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>

    <script lang="javascript">
        let whosTurn = "o";

        function clickedSquare(x1,x2, o) {

            console.log('hi!')
            var eleX = document.getElementById(x1);
            var eleXR = document.getElementById(x2)
            var eleO = document.getElementById(o);
           
            var eleXstyle = eleX.getAttribute("stroke");
            var eleXRstyle = eleXR.getAttribute("stroke");
            var eleOstyle = eleO.getAttribute("stroke");


            if (eleXstyle == "transparent" && eleOstyle == "transparent") {
                if (whosTurn = "x") {
                     eleXstyle == "black"
                     eleXRstyle =="black"
                eleX.setAttribute( "stroke", "black");
                eleXR.setAttribute( "stroke", "black");
                    whosTurn = "o"
                   
                } else {
                 eleOstyle == "black"
                    eleO.setAttribute( "stroke", "black");
                    whosTurn = "x"

                }
            }
            console.log(whosTurn)
        }
      function checkForWinner() {
        
      }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <svg width="500" height="500" style="background-color: black;" viewBox="0 0 500 500">
        <rect width="160" height="160" x="0" y="0" fill="red" onclick="clickedSquare('x1l','x1r','circle1');"></rect>
        <rect width="160" height="160" x="170" y="0" fill="white" onclick="clickedSquare('x2l','x2r','circle2'); checkForWinner();"></rect>
        <rect width="160" height="160" x="340" y="0" fill="white" onclick="clickedSquare('x3l','x3r','circle3'); checkForWinner();"></rect>
        <rect width="160" height="160" x="0" y="170" fill="white" onclick="clickedSquare('x4l','x4r','circle4'); checkForWinner();"></rect>
        <rect width="160" height="160" x="170" y="170" fill="white" onclick="clickedSquare('x5l','x5r','circle5'); checkForWinner();"></rect>
        <rect width="160" height="160" x="340" y="170" fill="white" onclick="clickedSquare('x6l','x6r','circle6'); checkForWinner();"></rect>
        <rect width="160" height="160" x="0" y="340" fill="white" onclick="clickedSquare('x7l','x7r','circle7'); checkForWinner();"></rect>
        <rect width="160" height="160" x="170" y="340" fill="white" onclick="clickedSquare('x8l','x8r','circle8'); checkForWinner();"></rect>
        <rect width="160" height="160" x="340" y="340" fill="white" onclick="clickedSquare('x9l','x9r','circle9'); checkForWinner();"></rect>

        <line x1="20" y1="20" x2="130" y2="120" stroke="transparent" stroke-width="5px" class="exes x1" id="x1l"></line>
        <line x1="130" y1="20" x2="20" y2="120" stroke="transparent" stroke-width="5px" class="exes x1" id="x1r"></line>

        <line x1="190" y1="20" x2="300" y2="120" stroke="transparent" stroke-width="5px" class="exes x2" id="x2l"></line>
        <line x1="300" y1="20" x2="190" y2="120" stroke="transparent" stroke-width="5px" class="exes x2" id="x2r"></line>
        
        <line x1="360" y1="20" x2="470" y2="120" stroke="transparent" stroke-width="5px" class="exes x3" id="x3l"></line>
        <line x1="470" y1="20" x2="360" y2="120" stroke="transparent" stroke-width="5px" class="exes x3" id="x3r"></line>


        <line x1="20" y1="190" x2="130" y2="290" stroke="transparent" stroke-width="5px" class="exes x4" id="x4l"></line>
        <line x1="130" y1="190" x2="20" y2="290" stroke="transparent" stroke-width="5px" class="exes x4" id="x4r"></line>

        <line x1="190" y1="190" x2="300" y2="290" stroke="transparent" stroke-width="5px" class="exes x5" id="x5l"></line>
        <line x1="300" y1="190" x2="190" y2="290" stroke="transparent" stroke-width="5px" class="exes x5" id="x5r"></line>
        
        <line x1="360" y1="190" x2="470" y2="290" stroke="transparent" stroke-width="5px" class="exes x6" id="x6l"></line>
        <line x1="470" y1="190" x2="360" y2="290" stroke="transparent" stroke-width="5px" class="exes x6" id="x6r"></line>
        
        
        <line x1="20" y1="360" x2="130" y2="470" stroke="transparent" stroke-width="5px" class="exes x7" id="x7l"></line>
        <line x1="130" y1="360" x2="20" y2="470" stroke="transparent" stroke-width="5px" class="exes x7" id="x7r"></line>

        <line x1="190" y1="360" x2="300" y2="470" stroke="transparent" stroke-width="5px" class="exes x8" id="x8l"></line>
        <line x1="300" y1="360" x2="190" y2="470" stroke="transparent" stroke-width="5px" class="exes x8" id="x8r"></line>
        
        <line x1="360" y1="360" x2="470" y2="470" stroke="transparent" stroke-width="5px" class="exes x9" id="x9l"></line>
        <line x1="470" y1="360" x2="360" y2="470" stroke="transparent" stroke-width="5px" class="exes x9" id="x9r"></line>
       
        <circle cx="70" cy="70" r="60" stroke="transparent" stroke-width="5px" fill="transparent" class="circle" id="circle1"></circle>
        <circle cx="250" cy="70" r="60" stroke="transparent" stroke-width="5px" fill="transparent" class="circle" id="circle2"></circle>
        <circle cx="430" cy="70" r="60" stroke="transparent" stroke-width="5px" fill="transparent" class="circle" id="circle3"></circle>

        <circle cx="70" cy="250" r="60" stroke="transparent" stroke-width="5px" fill="transparent" class="circle" id="circle4"></circle>
        <circle cx="250" cy="250" r="60" stroke="transparent" stroke-width="5px" fill="transparent" class="circle" id="circle5"></circle>
        <circle cx="430" cy="250" r="60" stroke="transparent" stroke-width="5px" fill="transparent" class="circle" id="circle6"></circle>

        <circle cx="70" cy="430" r="60" stroke="transparent" stroke-width="5px" fill="transparent" class="circle" id="circle7"></circle>
        <circle cx="250" cy="430" r="60" stroke="transparent" stroke-width="5px" fill="transparent" class="circle" id="circle8"></circle>
        <circle cx="430" cy="430" r="60" stroke="transparent" stroke-width="5px" fill="transparent" class="circle" id="circle9"></circle>

    </svg>
    <script>
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The circle and the lines are bloking the event. Try adding `circle, line { pointer-events : none}` to the CSS

Comment: why is the first square red? is there a particular reason for this?

Answer (score 0):

The main problem was: in the SVG version 1.1 the rendering order happens based on the order of items. So, in your implementation you can click only in the surrounding area in every rect. 
I solved the problem by using the display attribute (equals to  null). Which will remove the element from the document. As a result, you can click anywhere inside the rect element.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Document</title>

    <script lang="javascript">
        let whosTurn = "o";

        function clickedSquare(x1, x2, o) {

            console.log('hi!')
            var eleX = document.getElementById(x1);
            var eleXR = document.getElementById(x2)
            var eleO = document.getElementById(o);

            var eleXstyle = eleX.getAttribute("display");
            var eleXRstyle = eleXR.getAttribute("display");
            var eleOstyle = eleO.getAttribute("display");

            console.log("whosTurn=", whosTurn)
            console.log("eleXstyle=", eleXstyle)
            console.log("eleXRstyle=", eleXRstyle)
            console.log("eleOstyle=", eleOstyle)
            if (eleXstyle === "none" && eleOstyle === "none") {
                if (whosTurn === "x") {
                    eleXstyle = "inline"
                    eleXRstyle = "inline"
                    eleX.setAttribute("display", "inline");
                    eleXR.setAttribute("display", "inline");
                    whosTurn = "o"

                } else {
                    eleOstyle = "inline"
                    eleO.setAttribute("display", "inline");
                    whosTurn = "x"

                }
            }
            console.log(whosTurn)
        }
        function checkForWinner() {

        }
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <svg width="500" height="500" style="background-color: black" viewBox="0 0 500 500">
        <rect width="160" height="160" x="0" y="0" fill="red" onclick="clickedSquare('x1l','x1r','circle1');"></rect>
        <rect width="160" height="160" x="170" y="0" fill="white"
            onclick="clickedSquare('x2l','x2r','circle2'); checkForWinner();"></rect>
        <rect width="160" height="160" x="340" y="0" fill="white"
            onclick="clickedSquare('x3l','x3r','circle3'); checkForWinner();"></rect>
        <rect width="160" height="160" x="0" y="170" fill="white"
            onclick="clickedSquare('x4l','x4r','circle4'); checkForWinner();"></rect>
        <rect width="160" height="160" x="170" y="170" fill="white"
            onclick="clickedSquare('x5l','x5r','circle5'); checkForWinner();"></rect>
        <rect width="160" height="160" x="340" y="170" fill="white"
            onclick="clickedSquare('x6l','x6r','circle6'); checkForWinner();"></rect>
        <rect width="160" height="160" x="0" y="340" fill="white"
            onclick="clickedSquare('x7l','x7r','circle7'); checkForWinner();"></rect>
        <rect width="160" height="160" x="170" y="340" fill="white"
            onclick="clickedSquare('x8l','x8r','circle8'); checkForWinner();"></rect>
        <rect width="160" height="160" x="340" y="340" fill="white"
            onclick="clickedSquare('x9l','x9r','circle9'); checkForWinner();"></rect>

        <line x1="20" y1="20" x2="130" y2="120" display="none" stroke="black" stroke-width="5px" class="exes x1"
            id="x1l"></line>
        <line x1="130" y1="20" x2="20" y2="120" display="none" stroke="black" stroke-width="5px" class="exes x1"
            id="x1r"></line>

        <line x1="190" y1="20" x2="300" y2="120" display="none" stroke="black" stroke-width="5px" class="exes x2"
            id="x2l">
        </line>
        <line x1="300" y1="20" x2="190" y2="120" display="none" stroke="black" stroke-width="5px" class="exes x2"
            id="x2r">
        </line>

        <line x1="360" y1="20" x2="470" y2="120" display="none" stroke="black" stroke-width="5px" class="exes x3"
            id="x3l">
        </line>
        <line x1="470" y1="20" x2="360" y2="120" display="none" stroke="black" stroke-width="5px" class="exes x3"
            id="x3r">
        </line>

        <line x1="20" y1="190" x2="130" y2="290" display="none" stroke="black" stroke-width="5px" class="exes x4"
            id="x4l">
        </line>
        <line x1="130" y1="190" x2="20" y2="290" display="none" stroke="black" stroke-width="5px" class="exes x4"
            id="x4r">
        </line>

        <line x1="190" y1="190" x2="300" y2="290" display="none" stroke="black" stroke-width="5px" class="exes x5"
            id="x5l">
        </line>
        <line x1="300" y1="190" x2="190" y2="290" display="none" stroke="black" stroke-width="5px" class="exes x5"
            id="x5r">
        </line>

        <line x1="360" y1="190" x2="470" y2="290" display="none" stroke="black" stroke-width="5px" class="exes x6"
            id="x6l">
        </line>
        <line x1="470" y1="190" x2="360" y2="290" display="none" stroke="black" stroke-width="5px" class="exes x6"
            id="x6r">
        </line>

        <line x1="20" y1="360" x2="130" y2="470" display="none" stroke="black" stroke-width="5px" class="exes x7"
            id="x7l">
        </line>
        <line x1="130" y1="360" x2="20" y2="470" display="none" stroke="black" stroke-width="5px" class="exes x7"
            id="x7r">
        </line>

        <line x1="190" y1="360" x2="300" y2="470" display="none" stroke="black" stroke-width="5px" class="exes x8"
            id="x8l">
        </line>
        <line x1="300" y1="360" x2="190" y2="470" display="none" stroke="black" stroke-width="5px" class="exes x8"
            id="x8r">
        </line>

        <line x1="360" y1="360" x2="470" y2="470" display="none" stroke="black" stroke-width="5px" class="exes x9"
            id="x9l">
        </line>
        <line x1="470" y1="360" x2="360" y2="470" display="none" stroke="black" stroke-width="5px" class="exes x9"
            id="x9r">
        </line>

        <circle cx="70" cy="70" r="60" display="none" stroke="black" stroke-width="5px" fill="transparent"
            class="circle" id="circle1"></circle>
        <circle cx="250" cy="70" r="60" display="none" stroke="black" stroke-width="5px" fill="transparent"
            class="circle" id="circle2"></circle>
        <circle cx="430" cy="70" r="60" display="none" stroke="black" stroke-width="5px" fill="transparent"
            class="circle" id="circle3"></circle>

        <circle cx="70" cy="250" r="60" display="none" stroke="black" stroke-width="5px" fill="transparent"
            class="circle" id="circle4"></circle>
        <circle cx="250" cy="250" r="60" display="none" stroke="black" stroke-width="5px" fill="transparent"
            class="circle" id="circle5"></circle>
        <circle cx="430" cy="250" r="60" display="none" stroke="black" stroke-width="5px" fill="transparent"
            class="circle" id="circle6"></circle>

        <circle cx="70" cy="430" r="60" display="none" stroke="black" stroke-width="5px" fill="transparent"
            class="circle" id="circle7"></circle>
        <circle cx="250" cy="430" r="60" display="none" stroke="black" stroke-width="5px" fill="transparent"
            class="circle" id="circle8"></circle>
        <circle cx="430" cy="430" r="60" display="none" stroke="black" stroke-width="5px" fill="transparent"
            class="circle" id="circle9"></circle>
    </svg>
    <script></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

just for a start:

```js
const
  svgNS         = 'http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'
, TicTacToeGrid = document.querySelector('#Tic-Tac-Toe-grid')
, gridRects     = TicTacToeGrid.querySelectorAll('rect')
, virtualGrid   = [['','',''],['','',''],['','','']]
, rects_Delta   = 170
, setAttributes = (elm,ats) =>
    Object.entries(ats).forEach(([k,v])=>elm.setAttribute(k,v))
, dialogBox     = document.querySelector('#dialog-box')
  ;
var setPlaying = set_X;
function set_O(x,y)
  {
  const calcPos = p => (p * rects_Delta) + 80;

  if (virtualGrid[x][y] !== '') return;

  virtualGrid[x][y] = 'o';
  nCircle = document.createElementNS(svgNS, 'circle');
  setAttributes(nCircle, { cx: calcPos(x), cy: calcPos(y), r: 60 });
  TicTacToeGrid.appendChild(nCircle);
  
  setPlaying = set_X;
  }
function set_X(x,y)
  {
  const 
    calc_TopRight = p => (p * rects_Delta) + 30
  , calc_BotLeft  = p => (p * rects_Delta) + 140
    ;  
  if (virtualGrid[x][y] !== '') return;

  virtualGrid[x][y] = 'x';
  bar_1 = document.createElementNS(svgNS, 'line');
  bar_2 = document.createElementNS(svgNS, 'line');

  setAttributes(bar_1, { x1: calc_TopRight(x), x2:calc_BotLeft(x), y1: calc_TopRight(y), y2: calc_BotLeft(y) });
  setAttributes(bar_2, { x1: calc_BotLeft(x), x2:calc_TopRight(x), y1: calc_TopRight(y), y2: calc_BotLeft(y) });

  TicTacToeGrid.appendChild(bar_1);
  TicTacToeGrid.appendChild(bar_2);
  
  setPlaying = set_O;
  }
function endGame()
  {
  dialogBox.showModal();
  }
TicTacToeGrid.onclick = ({target: clikedElement}) =>
  {
  if (!clikedElement.matches('rect')) return;
  
  setPlaying( +clikedElement.getAttribute('x') / rects_Delta, +clikedElement.getAttribute('y') / rects_Delta );

  let {aWinnerIs,winRows} = checkWinner();
  
  if (aWinnerIs!=='')
    {
    setPlaying = endGame;
    winRows.split('/').map(s=>s.split('-').map(Number)).map(([x,y])=>x+(y*3))
      .forEach( pos => gridRects[pos].classList.add('win'));
    }
  } 
btClear.onclick =_=>
  {
  for (let i=3;i--;) 
  for (let j=3;j--;)
    virtualGrid[i][j] = '';

  TicTacToeGrid.querySelectorAll('rect').forEach(r=>r.classList.remove('win'));
  TicTacToeGrid.querySelectorAll('circle,line').forEach(elm=>elm.remove());

  setPlaying = set_X;
  }
function checkWinner()
  {
  let 
    aWinnerIs = ''
  , winRows   = ''
  , suite     = ''
    ;
  for (let i=3;i--;)
    {
    suite = virtualGrid[i].join('');
    if (suite==='xxx' || suite==='ooo')
      {
      aWinnerIs = suite[0];
      winRows   = `${i}-0/${i}-1/${i}-2`;
      break;
      }
    else
      {
      suite = virtualGrid[0][i] + virtualGrid[1][i] +virtualGrid[2][i];
      if (suite==='xxx' || suite==='ooo')
        {
        aWinnerIs = suite[0];
        winRows   = `0-${i}/1-${i}/2-${i}`;
        break;
        }
      }
    } // for 
    if (aWinnerIs==='')
    {
    suite = virtualGrid[0][0] + virtualGrid[1][1] +virtualGrid[2][2];
    if (suite==='xxx' || suite==='ooo')
      {
      aWinnerIs = suite[0];
      winRows   = `0-0/1-1/2-2`;
      }
    }
  if (aWinnerIs==='')
    {
    suite = virtualGrid[2][0] + virtualGrid[1][1] + virtualGrid[0][2];
    if (suite==='xxx' || suite==='ooo')
      {
      aWinnerIs = suite[0];
      winRows   = `2-0/1-1/0-2`;
      }
    }
  return ({aWinnerIs,winRows})
  }
```

```css
svg {
  --sqSize   : 250px;
  width      : var(--sqSize);
  height     : var(--sqSize);
  background : black;
  }
svg rect {
  cursor : pointer;
  fill   : white;
  }
svg rect:hover {
  fill   : lightblue;
  }
svg rect.win {
  fill   : gold;
  }
svg circle {
  stroke       : green;
  stroke-width : 10;
  fill         : transparent;
  }
svg line {
  stroke       : red;
  stroke-width : 10;
  }
dialog::backdrop {
  background   : #00ddff5d;
  }
```

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 500 500" id="Tic-Tac-Toe-grid">
  <rect x="0"   y="0"   width="160" height="160" />
  <rect x="170" y="0"   width="160" height="160" />
  <rect x="340" y="0"   width="160" height="160" />
  <rect x="0"   y="170" width="160" height="160" />
  <rect x="170" y="170" width="160" height="160" />
  <rect x="340" y="170" width="160" height="160" />
  <rect x="0"   y="340" width="160" height="160" />
  <rect x="170" y="340" width="160" height="160" />
  <rect x="340" y="340" width="160" height="160" />
</svg>

<button id="btClear">Clear</button>

<dialog id="dialog-box">
  <form method="dialog">
    <p>Game is Over !</p>
    <button>OK</button>
  </form>
</dialog>
```